# Escaping double qoutes when sending JSON as argument in python program

Tags: python, json

I know there are many similar issues but I didn't manage to find the answer to my issue.
The problem I having is I can't properly escape the double-quotes.
This is my JSON string:

```
"{"source":{"datatype":"panorama","project":"Test project","zoomlevel":19,"imageids": [14295321, 14295325, 14295332, 14295303, 14295301]}}"
```

If I manually modifying the JSON string like this:

```
"{\"source\":{\"datatype\":\"panorama\",\"project\":\"Test project\",\"zoomlevel\":19,\"imageids\": [14295321, 14295325, 14295332, 14295303, 14295301]}}"
```

And sending this to my python script:

```
import json
import sys

input_argv = str(sys.argv[1])
input_str = json.loads(input_argv)
image_ids = input_str['source']['imageids']
image_id = image_ids[0]
project_name = input_str['source']['project']

print(image_id, project_name)
```

And it works as expected. However, if I use not modified JSON string and sending it to the following script:

```
import json
import sys

input_argv = str(sys.argv[1])
input_clean = input_argv.replace('"','\"')
input_str = json.loads(input_clean)
image_ids = input_str['source']['imageids']
image_id = image_ids[0]
project_name = input_str['source']['project']

print(image_id, project_name)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I have tried what I could but without any success.
Could someone help me with it?

Comment: Use single quotes to quote the whole string and do not escape double quotes at all.

Comment: Single quotes didn't help.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GZXx3Y6.png

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you for your help. I have tested single quotes on linux Ubuntu and indeed it worked. But funny think the same code fails on my windows machine with error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes have special meaning in shell. You will need to pass the input with escaped double quotes or single quotes without escaping the double quotes

```
python app.py '{"arg":"value"}'
```

or

```
python app.py "{\"arg\":\"value\"}"
```

if you are passing the json as is you will be something like

```
{arg:value}
```

Now if it is a flat dictionary you can go ahead and manipulate this string to {"arg":"value"} by writing a custom function, but as the JSON gets complicated this is not a viable approach, as there can be edge cases coming up

A better implementation would be to read this JSON data from a file and pass the file path as argument to your script instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Single quotes didn't help. It gives me an error. However, passing string from file works as expected.