# Passing array object from PHP to Python

Tags: python, php, json

This is my code so far

```
    $dataraw = $_SESSION['image'];
    $datagambar = json_encode($dataraw);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($dataraw);
    echo '</pre>';

    print($escaped_json);

    $type1 = gettype($dataraw);
    print($type1);

    $type2 = gettype($datagambar);
    print($type2);
```

This is $dataraw output, the type is array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => 20221227_202035.jpg
            [Model] => SM-A528B
            [Longitude] => 106.904251
            [Latitude] => -6.167665
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => 20221227_202157.jpg
            [Model] => SM-A528B
            [Longitude] => 106.9042428
            [Latitude] => -6.1676580997222
        )

)
```

This is $datagambar output, the type is string

```
[{"FileName":"20221227_202035.jpg","Model":"SM-A528B","Longitude":106.904251,"Latitude":-6.167665},{"FileName":"20221227_202157.jpg","Model":"SM-A528B","Longitude":106.9042428,"Latitude":-6.167658099722223}]
```

Pass to python

```
echo shell_exec("D:\Anaconda\python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py $datagambar");
```

This is my python test.py

```
import sys, json
import os
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors as mpl
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,hamming_loss,classification_report

json_list = []
escaped_json1 = sys.argv[1]

# this is working but its only a string of array json
# print(escaped_json1) 
# this is working but its only a string of array json

json_list.append(json.loads(escaped_json1))
parsed_data = json.loads(escaped_json1) 
print(json_list)
print(parsed_data)
```

When i do print(escaped_json1) it display a string of array json from php($datagambar).

python output:

```
Hello world has been called [{"FileName":"20221227_202035.jpg","Model":"SM-A528B","Longitude":106.904251,"Latitude":-6.167665},{"FileName":"20221227_202157.jpg","Model":"SM-A528B","Longitude":106.9042428,"Latitude":-6.167658099722223}]
```

I use apache as my server with phpmyadmin and anaconda.

T tried using print(type(escapedjson1))
or print(type(escapedjson1)) but it doesn't display the type

json.loads didn't change the type of data to python array

How to loads it and make the string array into a variable array so i can call it and convert it to dataframe?.

Comment: Maybe the shell is not interpreting the value of the `$datagambar` variable as a single argument, which is why you can see some output when you print it, but fails to parse as it may not be valid JSON, you can try wrapping the variable in single quotes: `echo shell_exec("D:\Anaconda\python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py '$datagambar'");`

Comment: Nope, escaping arguments doesn't work by simply wrapping them into single quotes, @RJK. You must do it properly, otherwise you risk code injection. Actually, I'd prefer an interface like `pcntl_exec()`, where you don't put a shell in the middle, but that function is POSIX-only, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you share the output of `print(type(escaped_json1))`

Comment: @executable it didn't print out anything

Comment: You should just use a temporary file to transmit your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: A Completely different approach**

There is a difficulty with the PHP script JSON-encoding a structure to produce a JSON string and then passing it as a command line argument since the string needs to be placed in double quotes because there can be embedded spaces in the encoded string. But the string itself can contain double quotes as start of string characters and within such a string. Confused? Who wouldn't be?

There is no problem however with writing such a string to a file and having the Python program read it in and decode it. But we don't want to have to deal with temporary files. So the solution is to *pipe* the data to the Python program where it can then be read in as *stdin*

Let's assume your array looks like:

```php
$arr =
[
    [
        "FileName" => "\"\\  \nRon's20221227_202035.jpg",
        "Model" => "27_202035.jpg",
        "Longitude" => 106.90425,
        "Latitude" => 106.90425
    ],
    [
        "FileName" => "20221227_202157.jpg",
        "Model" => "SM-A528B",
        "Longitude" => 106.9042428,
        "Latitude" => -6.1676580997222
    ]
];
```

Note that I have modified your example slightly so that the first `FileName` field contains a `"` character, a `'` character, an escape sequence `\n` representing the newline character and finally some spaces. Although your example does not contain these characters or some other escape sequence, I would like to be able to handle such a condition should it arise. This solution should work with such input.

**PHP File**

```PHP
<?php
$arr =
[
    [
        "FileName" => "\"\\  \nRon's20221227_202035.jpg",
        "Model" => "27_202035.jpg",
        "Longitude" => 106.90425,
        "Latitude" => 106.90425
    ],
    [
        "FileName" => "20221227_202157.jpg",
        "Model" => "SM-A528B",
        "Longitude" => 106.9042428,
        "Latitude" => -6.1676580997222
    ]
];

// Encode string as JSON:
$json = json_encode($arr);

// Pipe the JSON string to the Python process's stdin and
// read the result from its stdout:
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w")   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
);
$options = array('bypass_shell' => True); // Only has effect on Windows
//$process = proc_open("python3 test.py", $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null, $options);
// For your actual environment:
$process = proc_open("D:/Anaconda/python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py", $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null, $options);

// Pipe the input for the Python program and close the pipe:
fwrite($pipes[0], $json);
fclose($pipes[0]);

// Read the result from the Python program and close its pipe
$result = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

# Now that we have closed the pipes, we can close the process:
$return_code = proc_close($process);

echo "Result from stdin:\n$result\n";
```

**test.py**

```py
import json
import sys

DEBUG = True # for debugging purposes

if DEBUG:
    import os

    for k, v in sorted(os.environ.items()):
        print(k, '->', v, file=sys.stderr)
else:
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

# Load from stdin:
arr = json.load(sys.stdin)
# print each dictionary of the array:
for d in arr:
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```None
{'FileName': '"\\  \nRon\'s20221227_202035.jpg', 'Model': '27_202035.jpg', 'Longitude': 106.90425, 'Latitude': 106.90425}
{'FileName': '20221227_202157.jpg', 'Model': 'SM-A528B', 'Longitude': 106.9042428, 'Latitude': -6.1676580997222}
```

Comment: Thankyou for replying this.. im still studying your answer, are you making a format that can works with json.loads? does my array can be change into like yours?

Comment: See my Python file above; it does a `json.loads()` against the passed argument to the program. The program first prints out the passed argument, which is a string, then it prints the result of running `json.loads()` against that string, which is a Python list and finally the code prints each element of the list, which is a Python dictionary. Each of these three print operations is separated by a dashed line (see above output).

Comment: *"can be simplified by double-encoding the array"* You shouldn't use `json_encode()` on the string to escape it. It happens to work but it's just an accident. It's not meant for that.

Comment: @Olivier See the updated code; it's a completely different and more robust approach (in my opinion, anyway).

Comment: A file approach is definitely much better (personally I would just use a temp file). Did you see the note on the [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) page regarding the `bypass_shell` option? It looks safer to use it.

Comment: @Olivier It might be faster but I don't see how in this case it's safer. BTW, it's a Windows-only option. If it  had general applicability then I could see how it would have an effect on whether wild-card expansion of arguments was done or not on Linux, for example.. But faster is good.

Comment: @Booboo Sir, why if i import packages other than sys and json makes the php shell_exec didn't run the python file? such as pandas, numpy or matplotlib.

Comment: I added imports for `pandas` and `numpy` and it still worked for me. It does take time to load these large packages so the response will not come back as fast. Are you sure that was the only changes you made? Perhaps you need to post what exactly your Python file looked like.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the latest Python source showing the additonal imports. I am also using `json.load()` directly against `sys.stdin` rather than first reading the input and then using `json.loads()`. The two ways are equivalent but this is now one line shorter.

Comment: You can also try running **python3 test.py** from the command line and then entering **[1,2]** followed by the enter key followed by either Ctrl-Z (Windows) or Ctrl-D (Linux) to signal end-of-file. See if any error messages are produced. But if you run my code above exactly, it should just print out 1 and 2 on separate lines.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned `shell_exec` in your comment. My updated answer does not use this call. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: @Booboo You can check this video that when there is imported packages the code is not run https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nREl3toV6w0b-nXEOTPNkrjg1BtqL44_/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I can't really follow your "demo." What does your PHP code look like? Does it look like my code above?

Comment: @Booboo I copied exactly as your code

Comment: I don't know what your environment is. Have you tried running this from the command line with **python3 test.py** as I posed a few comments ago?

Comment: python3 test.py didn't run the python code, im using anaconda base environment.

D:\xampp\htdocs\Klasifikasi_KNN>python3 test.py
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

D:\xampp\htdocs\Klasifikasi_KNN>python3 test.py
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: You can't run an Anaconda Python program from the command line? And how is the input JSON being fed to this? Is yoru demo running a PHP program? My request above was for you to type in **[1,2}** etc. to just the Python program so we might see any error messages. Frankly, I have no idea what it is you are executing in that video.

Comment: I mean you clearly need to modify the PHP program so it points to your Python executable and Python source, so you would be coding in the PHP program: `proc_open("D:\Anaconda\python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py", etc.)`

Comment: @Booboo ohh yess sorry.., before i changed it into proc_open("D:\Anaconda\python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py", etc.) because before with python test.py it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251156/discussion-between-jessen-jie-and-booboo).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to enclose in single quotes the argument to python:

`shell_exec("python3 test.py '$json'");`

#### Example

**file.php**

```
$data =
[
    [
        "FileName" => "20221227_202035.jpg",
        "Model" => "27_202035.jpg",
        "Longitude" => 106.90425,
        "Latitude" => 106.90425
    ],
    [
        "FileName" => "20221227_202157.jpg",
        "Model" => "SM-A528B",
        "Longitude" => 106.9042428,
        "Latitude" => -6.1676580997222
    ]
];

$json = json_encode($data);

// note: arg '$json' is single-quoted
echo shell_exec("python3 test.py '$json'");
```

**test.py**

```
import sys
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

data = sys.argv[1]

dict = json.loads(data)
df2 = json_normalize(dict) 

print(df2)
```

Output

```
              FileName     Model   Longitude  Latitude
0  20221227_202035.jpg  SM-A528B  106.904251 -6.167665
1  20221227_202157.jpg  SM-A528B  106.904243 -6.167658
```

See:
[Escaping double qoutes when sending JSON as argument in python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558967/escaping-double-qoutes-when-sending-json-as-argument-in-python-program)

Comment: Thankyou calo for answering. it didn't run the python file if i import from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

Comment: In **file.php** your `$json`  variable is a *string* and not an *array* as in the actual input the OP needs to process.

Comment: @Booboo yes its a string of json array because shell exec from php cannot explicitly pass array to python. If i pass the $dataraw itself and not encode it first to $datagambar i get Warning: Array to string conversion

Comment: @calogero Your output is what im looking for... im running my php with apache server phpMyAdmin. When i try to import pandas only without using it or do anything else php is not executing the python file using shell_exec..

Comment: @JessenJie Are you using your string instead of mine ("python3 test.py $json")?

Comment: @calogero i've tried your strings too it works the same as $datagambar.

Comment: @calogero The json.loads is executed and can be printed, but the output is still json strings.. i think? because i can't check the type using print(type(data))

Comment: `print(type(dict))` gives `<class 'list'>` to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251120/discussion-between-calogero-and-jessen-jie).

Comment: As @Booboo said, the initial input is an array. I edited my answer to reflect that. I hope it can help.

Comment: *"You just need to enclose in single quotes"* Did you test it on Windows? And what happens if the JSON string contains single quotes?